# method like rdd for binary outcome variable?

Tags: regression, binary-data, regression-discontinuity

I'm currently writing my first empirical term paper and would like to model the following relationship.
I'm mainly interested how government spending, which regions are mostly only eligible to if their regional gdp falls below a certain threshold, affects regime approval. The latter is measured as a binary variable in the survey. I do not have data on exactly how much is spent in each region, but can see from other studies that there is a strong drop at that threshold. In my mind, I am looking for something that combines logistic regression and fuzzy regression discontinuity.
Any hints on how one might want to do something like that (or if you think this is generally a horrible idea, also feel free to tell me) are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Wouldn’t you just run the RDD but with a logistic (maybe probit) model?

Comment: Thank you, I looked into that but couldn't really find any applications of it. Do you maybe know a source where I can find out more about it?

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304407617301471